# Contents drawn in the CGContext gets dissapeared

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Contents drawn on the CGContext of the UIImageView got disappeared. I have attached the video which demonstrates the issue i was facing in my side. I am getting this issue only in iOS 11 iPad. I could not reproduce the issue in iPod/iPhone with iOS 11. Can you please let me know if you have any idea on this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nhnaqdhh8ha7u1/Untitled.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please show us your code .